# ambiguous behavior for function ref as arg

Tags: java, java-8

I got an ambiguous behavior on a given code below:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        labo(Main::myFunction);
        labo(Main::myFunctionWithNoArgs);//Compiletime exception!!!
        labo(String::toUpperCase);//Compiled line!!!
    }

    public static void labo(Function<String,String> function){
        System.out.println(function.apply("test"));
    }

    public static String myFunction(String arg){
        return arg;
    }

    public static String myFunctionWithNoArgs(){
        return "";
    }
}
```

My question is: I don't understand why I didn't get a compiletime exception for arg String::toUpperCase and no for Main::myFunctionWithNoArgs even if toUpperCase() is a method without args same as myFunctionWithNoArgs()

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: `myFunctionWithNoArgs` isn't a `Function<String,String>`. It doesn't take a String as input.

Comment: Yes I know toUpperCase too I didn't get a compileTime Exception

Comment: `String::toUpperCase` _does_ take one string and output another.

Answer (score 2):

`String::toUpperCase` is equivalent to `s -> s.toUpperCase()` in this context, ie it is a function from `String` to `String`.

The "argument" here is the receiver of the method, ie the `String` betting converted to upper case.

Answer (score 1):

May be if you write that as a lambda it would make a lot more sense:

```
labo(t -> t.toUpperCase())
```